# Weird Extended Information on Nagios Web UI

Tags: apache-2.2, nagios

Below are screenshots when I click on any Service/Host Extended Information:

The weird info at the top:

[image: At the top is weird info]

The content of line begin with `__gmon_start_libc.so...`:

```
__gmon_start__libc.so.6fflushstrcpy__rawmemchrgmtime_rexitreaddirfopenstrrchr__strdupclosedirstrncpyputsputcharreallocstdinstrpbrklocaltime_rgmtimestrtokmmapfgetscallocstrlenmemsetstrstr__errno_locationstdoutmemcpyfcloserand__strtol_internalmallocstrcatstrcasecmpasprintfopendirgetenvsscanfsystemmunmapstrncasecmp__fxstatstrncatfreadlocaltimestrchrmktimeqsort__strtod_internal__ctype_toupper_loc__ctype_tolower_loc__xstatstrcmpstrerror__libc_start_mainsnprintf__strtoul_internalfreeGLIBC_2.3GLIBC_2.2.5
```

and the menus with poor formatting at the bottom:

[image: And bottom with poor formatting]

Click on any service command, it responses with a *"400 Bad request"* error.

The configuration in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"
    ServerName      xx
    ErrorLog    logs/nagios.error_log
    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
       Options ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
       Options None
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There is nothing in Apache's error log related to this.

I've updated to the latest version 3.3.1:

```
nagios -v

Nagios Core 3.3.1
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 07-25-2011
License: GPL
```

but it remains.

The permisison of `extinfo.cgi`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 nagios nagios 285528 Sep 15 17:52 extinfo.cgi
```

What should I take at look at first to debug this case?

---

**UPDATE**

I've added the `ScriptLog` directive to nagios virtual host:

```
ScriptLog logs/cgi_log
```

This file is created and `chmod` manually:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 Sep 20 11:46 /var/log/httpd/cgi_log
```

Go to browser to replicate this error but log is empty. Does anyone have another idea?

---

**UPDATE 2**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/TU4GPMrn) is the output when running `extinfo.cgi` from command line as `apache` user:

```
# REQUEST_METHOD=GET QUERY_STRING="?type=2&host=149&service=Disk_Free" REMOTE_USER="quanta" ./extinfo.cgi
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

> You mentioned other CGIs that are working, are they also called .cgi?

Of course. All the remaining .cgi scripts in `/usr/local/nagios/sbin/` work fine. E.g `status.cgi`:

[image: Service Status Details For All Hosts]

> The way you've configured the ScriptLog should be printing info.

But it didn't. This log file is blank.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 Sep 20 11:46 /var/log/httpd/cgi_log
```

> It looks like you have AllowOverride turned off for this directory,
>   but perhaps the apache configuration allows it for other directories
>   higher up? In that case make sure you haven't disabled ExecCGI or have
>   any .htaccess files in any directory above the nginx sbin.

There is no `.htaccess` file in `/usr/local/nagios`. I also compared this configuration with another file which is working, there is no significant difference:

```
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi"

<Directory "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi">
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/share/nagios"

<Directory "/usr/share/nagios">
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

> If that doesn't work I'd increase the apache log level:

I did it but there is nothing related to cgi in error log:

```
proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 3586 for (*)
proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 3587 for worker proxy:revers

proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 3587 for (*)
```

> If none of that points out the problem I'd probably strace apache
>   after setting it to only run a single child and seeing the output of a
>   working CGI vs a non-working CGI to see what the issue is.

Good point. I enclosed here the strace files.

Trace only open files:

```
strace -e trace=open -o /tmp/*.strace /usr/sbin/httpd -X
```

- `extinfo.cgi` (didn't work): http://pastebin.com/PKggyzfK
- `status.cgi` (works): http://pastebin.com/Gg6WwntJ

Trace full:

```
strace -o /tmp/*.strace /usr/sbin/httpd -X
```

- `extinfo.cgi`: http://www.mediafire.com/?c0du4p55pn7oh76
- `status.cgi`: http://www.mediafire.com/?1atvyecswmbv0sy

Take a look at if you can help.

Comment: It looks like Nagios is *reading* extinfo.cgi and not *executing* it.

Comment: `ls -al extinfo.cgi`?

Comment: It has permission 775, owner and group is `nagios`.

Comment: Is this a new phenomenon, or has it always been like this?

Comment: It occured a few days ago and I can't remember doing anything to cause this.

Comment: what happens when you try to run it?  ./extinfo.cgi?

Comment: @polynomial: I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you strace -f?  I don't see the execution of status.cgi in the strace output, and its odd that in the extinfo.cgi something appears to abort/terminate extinfo.cgi.  Have you checked syslog or dmesg for errors?

Comment: Updated my question. I run Apache in debug mode with single process, so no need to use `-f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rename `extinfo.cgi`, will it run under another name? If the script will be executed after renaming, most likely some parts of your Apache config handle the `extinfo.cgi` name in some unintended way. E.g., in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/satisfy.conf` you have:

```
<LocationMatch "/info(1|2).php">
```

This section will actually be applied to all requests which contain a matching part *anywhere* in the URL (because the regexp pattern is not anchored). E.g., it would apply to `/info1.php`, `/some/dir/info2.php`, `/dir/info1_php_anything/and/more` (note that a dot in regex matches any character, you need to write `\.` to match a literal dot). Also, `Location` and `LocationMatch` sections are always applied at the last step and override everything else (`.htaccess`, `Directory`, `Files`), and sections outside a `VirtualHost` definition are applied to all virtual hosts.

If your config files contain other similar sloppy `LocationMatch` patterns, maybe some of them match `/nagios/cgi-bin/extinfo.cgi` and break CGI handling just for this particular script name.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! You save my week. I have added a `<FilesMatch info>` directive in a `.conf` file to test `ForceType` and `SetHandler` for PHP, and... forget doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The *ScriptAlias* directive is provided by **mod_alias**, but files in directories marked with this directive are processed by **mod_cgi**.

Check if your **mod_cgi** is properly loaded.

Comment: Sure, it is loaded. Other cgi scripts such as `status.cgi` still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident this is a configuration issue, probably related to AddHandler.  The output you provided as @Vladimir Blaskov also pointed out indicates apache doesn't think this is a cgi.  You mentioned other CGIs that are working, are they also called .cgi?  Or are they just in the directory that allows ExecCGI with no suffix?  Also from the docs:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html#configuring

The way you've configured the ScriptLog should be printing info.  If I were in your situation I'd check a couple things:

Make sure you have a valid AddHandler:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

for .cgi, or test that other .cgi's are working in the same directory as extinfo.cgi.

It looks like you have AllowOverride turned off for this directory, but perhaps the apache configuration allows it for other directories higher up?  In that case make sure you haven't disabled ExecCGI or have any .htaccess files in any directory above the nginx sbin.

If that doesn't work I'd increase the apache log level:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#loglevel

```
LogLevel debug
```

then see if that prints anything related to why that file or directory isn't being handled as a CGI.

If none of that points out the problem I'd probably strace apache after setting it to only run a single child and seeing the output of a working CGI vs a non-working CGI to see what the issue is.  This sort of test would expose if maybe there is a configuration issue with the logging so that apache isn't able to write out helpful messages to the CGI log telling us why it refuses to play ball.  Hopefully you don't get all the way down to this part before fixing it, if you do I'll be really curious what the diagnostics showed.